# Dreaded python encoding errors, how to stop them?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

These have been plaguing me endlessly. Why? It seems that my console can't handle the encoding. I take it that the my browser and word processor can handle it. I don't have a master list of all the possible characters that it's choking on. What is the best way to relieve this without modifying my data?

```
'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\xca'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out the encoding of your console (which system, OS, etc...?) -- `'charmap'` is unfortunately a somewhat-ambiguous identification for a codec, as [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html?highlight=charmap#encodings-and-unicode) explain:

> There’s another group of encodings
>   (the so called **charmap** encodings) that
>   choose a different subset of all
>   unicode code points and how these
>   codepoints are mapped to the bytes
>   0x0-0xff. To see how this is done
>   simply open e.g. encodings/cp1252.py
>   (which is an encoding that is used
>   primarily on Windows). There’s a
>   string constant with 256 characters
>   that shows you which character is
>   mapped to which byte value.
>
> All of these encodings can only encode
>   256 of the 65536 (or 1114111)
>   codepoints defined in unicode.

i.e., it identifies a set of possible codecs, not a specific one.

Once you know your console supports a codec named `'foobar'`, change your statements that are now

```
print(someunicode)
```

into

```
print(someunicode.encode('foobar'))
```

Comment: I'm on Windows 7, using iPython running through the standard Windows console. How do I find out which encodings are supported?

Comment: @Rhubarb, CP 1252 is probably what's supported (I'm not familiar with Windows 7, and you should open a specific question for that, but older versions of Windows invariably had CP 1252 support -- and CP 1252 is a charmap encoding, so that's a hint in this direction).

Comment: Don't try to input/output non-ASCII characters from/to console under IPython. It's just buggy. It's hard enough trying to get Unicode console IO to behave at the best of times; don't add the extra confusion of grappling with lower-level bugs. see eg. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ipython/+bug/339642

Comment: @bobince, sure, but once you call `.encode` you're putting out a stream of bytes, not unicode _qua_ unicode -- that works, if your encoding matches your console _and_ the unicode codepoints you're emitting (you might want an 'ignore' as the 2nd arg to `encode` to cover for the latter issue, perhaps).